# how can i fetch record month wise in between two dates in postgresql (grouping dates by their months)?

Tags: postgresql

> I am using below query for fetching the record month wise but it give
>   wrong data

```
SELECT 
     (count( server_time::timestamp::date)) , 
     min(server_time::timestamp::date) as "Month Date"
FROM 
     complaint_details_v2 
WHERE 
     server_time between '2018/08/01' and '2018/10/30' 
GROUP BY 
     floor((server_time::timestamp::date  - '2018/08/01'::date)/30)
ORDER BY 
     2 ASC
```

Result

```
Count Month Date
2774  2018-08-01
5893  2018-08-31
1193  2018-09-30
```

But result will be

```
Count Month Date
2774  2018-08-01
5893  2018-09-01
1193  2018-10-01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`date_trunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f86a1f649be9ed27cd64a108c0b50b31)

```
SELECT
    count(*), 
    date_trunc('month', servertime)::date as month_date
FROM log
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', servertime)
ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: @sumitkundan Thanks for accepting. It would be great if you could upvote as well :)